# Property 'MSStream' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs

**Property 'MSStream' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis**
Hi Stack Community. I have used this line of code as I want to find if I am working on a pc or android or ios. And it is shouting at me with this error
**Property 'MSStream' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis**
/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && this.MSStream

Please let me know if there is any other way to perform this task or if there is a way to bypass this. I have tried using TRY AND CATCH Statement. This error doesnot effect the code it is working fine but it produces an issue while creating a build for deployment.

Thank You Very Much

I have tried using TRY AND CATCH STATEMENT. I am using it in angular js file so it still throwing this error. The code is working fine but it is creating a problem while building.

Comment: /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && this.MSStream 

Line of code I am using

Answer (score 0):

To address this issue you can extend the global Window interface like this:

```js
declare global {
    interface Window {
        MSStream: any;
    }
}
```